# Send token registartion to server not worklng

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am trying to send push notification to sever and then get that data to client app using FCM and Amazon SNS.

I have implemented following.

```
String customPushData = "my custom data";
CreatePlatformEndpointRequest platformEndpointRequest = new CreatePlatformEndpointRequest();

platformEndpointRequest.setCustomUserData(customPushData);
platformEndpointRequest.setToken(token);
platformEndpointRequest.setPlatformApplicationArn(platformApplicationArn);
pushClient.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.AP_NORTHEAST_1));

CreatePlatformEndpointResult result = pushClient.createPlatformEndpoint(platformEndpointRequest);
String endpointArn = result.getEndpointArn();
```

When i tried to debug this. then,

Cursor didn't move from

```
CreatePlatformEndpointResult result = pushClient.createPlatformEndpoint(platformEndpointRequest);
```

When i check in my application in **console.aws.amazon.com/sns** then no token registered.

Where i an wrong and how can i processed to send data to sns and get back to another device?

Any hep would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

At the end i have make it working using following way.

I have put in `AsyncTask` and do following changes.

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("access Key", "secret Key");
                AmazonSNSClient pushClient = new AmazonSNSClient(awsCredentials);

                CreatePlatformEndpointRequest platformEndpointRequest = new CreatePlatformEndpointRequest();
                platformEndpointRequest.setToken(regToken);
                platformEndpointRequest.setPlatformApplicationArn(platformApplicationArn);
                pushClient.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.Region_Name));

                CreatePlatformEndpointResult result = pushClient.createPlatformEndpoint(platformEndpointRequest);
                Log.e("Registration result",result.toString());

         return null;
}
```

I am getting endpointARN in response.